# Mockito doNothing doesn't work when a Method called with void method call inside

Tags: java, junit, mockito, powermock

**Main Class**

```
public class BootSample {

    public int call(int m) {
        System.out.println("Entering into Call Method");
        int n = m*10;
        TestUtil testUtil = new TestUtil();
        testUtil.add(m, n);
        System.out.println("End of Call Method Value n : " + n);
        return n;
    }

}
```

**Util Class**

```
public class TestUtil {

    public void add(int a, int b) {
        System.out.println(" Entering into TestUtil Method ");
        int c = a +b;
        System.out.println(" End of TestUtil Method Value : " + c);
    }

}
```

**Test Class**

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class BootSampleTest {

    @Mock
    TestUtil testUtil; 

    @Before
    public void setup() {

    }

    @Test
    public void utilSuccess() throws Exception {
        BootSample bootSample = new BootSample();
        doNothing().when(testUtil).add(any(Integer.class),any(Integer.class));
        int result = bootSample.call(10); 
        assertEquals(result,100);
    }

}
```

Output :

```
Entering into Call Method
 Entering into TestUtil Method 
 End of TestUtil Method Value : 110
End of Call Method Value n : 100
```

---

I'm trying to mock util void method call with doNothing but doesn't work.Can anyone please help me with solution? I'm stuck with similar functionality in our application.

Comment: 1. This Test will always fail. 2. You need to mock your class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your `call` method is responsible for creating a `TestUtil` object, and that object can't be mocked. Try adding TestUtil as a constructor argument like so:

```
public class BootSample {

    private TestUtil testUtil;

    public BootSample(TestUtil testUtil) {
        this.testUtil = testUtil;
    }

    public int call(int m) {
        System.out.println("Entering into Call Method");
        int n = m*10;
        testUtil.add(m, n);
        System.out.println("End of Call Method Value n : " + n);
        return n;
    }
}
```

You then need to mock the `TestUtil` class and pass the mock to the `BootSample` class:

```
BootSample bootSample = new BootSample(testUtil);
```

Comment: public class BootSample {
 public BootSample(Object mac) {
  this.mac = mac;
 }
    public int call(int m) {
        System.out.println("Entering into Call Method");
        int n = m*10;
        TestUtil testUtil = new TestUtil();
        testUtil.add(m, n);
        System.out.println("End of Call Method Value n : " + n);
        return n;
    }
}
Caller 
BootSample bootSample = new BootSample(macObject);
bootSample.call(15);

Comment: Thank You @Eric .This works but I have another main constructor which accepts some value where i cannot create new constructor of BootSample with testUtil. Is there any alternative approach ? like above

Comment: If you can't add the `TestUtil` object to a new constructor or an existing constructor, then you could just set the `TestUtil` object using a setter and calling it. Somehow you're going to have to inject the mock, whether it is through a constructor or a setter.

Comment: Thank You very much.Can you explain little more on using setter that would be great help.Really appreciate your help.Thanks a ton.

Answer (score 1):

If you're seeing the System.out.printlns from your TestUtil class then it isn't mocked. It looks like you're missing the @InjectMocks on BootSample to tell Mockito to inject your mocked TestUtil into it.

See the example in the docs here: http://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.13.0/org/mockito/InjectMocks.html

Comment: If you use `@InjectMocks`, the `TestUtil` needs to be injected in your production as well, of course.

Comment: The `@InjectMocks` approach has the disadvantage that you can declare more mocks but "forget" to add them to the constructor parameters. Your test does not get a compile error. And by the rules of *TDD* you are not allowed to change the production code then...

Comment: Thank You Kevin for your input it was really helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Mockito.anyInt()` instead of `Integer.class`,
code example :

```
Mockito.doNothing().when(testUtil).add(Mockito.anyInt(),Mockito.anyInt());
```