# Mockito doNothing not working, void method is still executed

Tags: java, testing, junit, mockito

I'm trying to write a test method that would execute methodA, and want to skip methodB that's being called within methodA. I'm using Mockito's doNothing() to skip methodB, but the methodB is still getting executed.

```
public class Product extends ParentProduct{
    @Override
    public void methodB(boolean sync) {
        //some code
     }
}
```

This is the Service class that has method methodA that needs to be tested/executed.

```
public class Service{
    public Response methodA(Request request) {
         Product product = new Product();
         product.init();
         //want to skip the below line of code that calls methodB
         product.methodB(true);
         Response response = product.getResponse();
         return response;
         }
}
```

Following is the test method

```
import org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.*;

@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
public class ServiceTest {
    @Before
    public void setUp() throws IOException {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    }

    @Mock
    private Product product;

    @Test
    public void testServiceProduct() throws Exception {
        Service service = new Service();
        Request request = new Request();
        doNothing().when(product).methodB(any(Boolean.class));
        Response response = service.methodA(request);
        Assert.assertTrue(response.getMessage().equals("202"));
    }
}
```

How do I ensure that methodB is skipped and all other lines in methodA are executed? Why is doNothing() not working here?
Also I've tried the solution's listed here: [Mockito doNothing doesn't work when a Method called with void method call inside](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48197090/mockito-donothing-doesnt-work-when-a-method-called-with-void-method-call-inside)
[Why are my mocked methods not calld when executing a unit test?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74027324/why-are-my-mocked-methods-not-calld-when-executing-a-unit-test)
but this didn't work for me

Comment: You're creating a new product in your service;this is where the method is called on. The mocking happens on the mock product you create in the test.

Comment: Your mock does nothing because it isn't used anywhere. As @daniu said, you're creating a local `Product` inside your method. You need to provide that object from the outside which can then be injected as a mock.

Comment: You probably want to factor `Product product = new Product();` out to a separate method, so that you can stub it in a Spy of Service, and make it return your mock Product.

Comment: Also, you're using `product` multiple times in your method. So you either need to mock **all** method calls of that class or make `product` a `Spy`. Otherwise, the test will fail.

Comment: I assume it's merely a typo, but `return response();` doesn't use the `response` variable from the previous line.

Comment: @daniu so I should not create a mock for the Product class? How do I pass the object to doNothing() method in this case?

Comment: @Dookoto_Sea you're exactly missing the point. Currently, the method you want to test contains a **local** instance of `Product`, which isn't mockable. You definitely want to mock `Product`, but you need to write your class/method in such a way that it becomes *possible*. I.e. don't create a local instance of `Product` inside `methodA` (what does this even do, logically?). Provide a way to inject that product from the outside, e.g. making `product` an instance variable or adding `product` as an argument of `methodA`.